# User friendly way to describe maximum byte length?

Tags: error-message

Imagine you have a form on a webpage where some lengths can only be a certain number of **characters** long, and you want to show the user a friendly error message.

```
Best animal
[_crocodile__]
*ERROR: The maximum length for an animal name is 5 characters.*
```

Ok that's cool, but what if your limitation is actually number of **bytes** (so for multi-byte character sets the limit would actually be 2 characters here)?  What's the best way to describe that to the user?

Comment: I'd say that's simply a really bad limitation from a UX perspective. What's the business argument for that?

Comment: I second DA01, an example could perhaps also help into understanding the problem :-)

Comment: There are technical constraints as to byte storage on the backend.  Otherwise we'd go with characters for sure (or no limit)

Answer (score 1):

Most users will and shoukd probably not care/think about something being a multibyte string, I think some users may even be offended if you'd start limiting one encoding vs another, e.g. chinese characters vs latin, in which the chinese people wouldn't be allowed to say as much. This would require too much knowledge and will eventually confuse most users (perhaps even the technical ones, as the different encodings can behave differently). <sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksf7W.png)</sup> Let alone even the legal issues and many support calls/tickets.

I'd just go ahead and keep the worst case scenario in mind when modeling your data storage (although, by now, most systems can handle multibyte just fine). This is because some encodings will take more than 2 bytes (not fixed, e.g. unicode does this). <sup>[2]</sup>

As for the counter, you could just show a counter somewhere close to your textarea, but in an unobtrusive way. When I do these things, I tend to set a certain treshold of 2/3, so the interface looks more clean in the more commong situation that the users won't reach this limit. If they do, I'd reconsider changing the model and increasing the maximum length.

[image]
[image]

You can take a look at the comment text area in twitter/SE/... It's clear, and also very close to the region of interaction. They also sometimes "disable" the button when the limit has been crossed or highlight the problem. The latter will probably depend on the size of the form ;-) Also, if you'd test it out, those inputs work just as expected, entering any character (latin, chinese, ...) will simply count as one.

[image]

The more classic approach is to really "cut" of the text and disable adding extra letters at the end. Together with a counter that is a very effective way of (somewhat implicitly) communicating the limiting factor.[3]

### Sources

- [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksf7W.png) http://uxmas.com/2012/the-4-hs-of-writing-error-messages
- [2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290182/how-many-bytes-does-one-unicode-character-take
- [3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poka-yoke

Comment: In terms of not being limited on bytes because users should not care about mutibyte character sets ... the byte limit is a technical constraint on the backend. // Meanwhile, the character-count-remaining concept is cool! But sadly I don't think this approach will work in my case -- I can't do the length update as they type.

Comment: Perhaps a periodic scan instead? Anyway, why do you think it won't work? :-) (e.g. is it a technical reason, or a user oriented reason)

Comment: @jlarson In that case, as stated, I'd account for the worst case when adding some sort of character counter (e.g. one character is always 4 bytes long, thus, the maximum length is actually divided by 4), this is true for the error message and/or the counter.